# Cannot configure MySql connection with .Net Core template

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I have a problem with my connection to MySql database. I generated an app with ASP.NET Core with target version .NET Framework 4.6.1.

My connection string looks like this:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
   "Default": "server=localhost;port=xxxx;database=MmpDb;user=user;password=***;" },
```

I added `MySql.Data.Entities` references for `Mmp.EntityFrameworkCore` and `Mmp.Web.Host`

I overwrite EF DbContext:

```
public class MmpDbConfiguration : DbConfiguration
    {
        public MmpDbConfiguration()
        {
            SetDefaultConnectionFactory(new MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlConnectionFactory());
            SetProviderServices("MySql.Data.MySqlClient",
                new MySqlProviderServices());
        }
    }
```

When I run the command `dotnet ef database update` I get an error that `Keyword not supported: 'port'.`

Can somebody provide a solution for this issue please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since Entity Framework Core is new, there is not much mature drivers.
I suggest you to use Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql for MySql connection.

Then, delete all migration files becasue they are generated agains MsSql.
Then regenerate migration files using Add-Migration command and it should work.

You can also check related issue on ABP's github repository here https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/2267.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install these packages to your solution

```
Mysql.Data
Mysql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore
```

and then try to connect to mysql